# Tomcat / Geoserver returns 403 access denied after multiple REST API calls

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, geoserver

I'm running [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) 2.11.2 on Java 1.8.0_144 32 bits on Amazon Linux together with Tomcat 9 and ran into the following problem:

I the Geoserver [REST API](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/index.html) to automatically create users accounts. To create 450+ accounts I wrote a loop to generate the accounts. This went flawless till about account 137. After that I got a access denied:

```
HTTP 403 status Forbidden
Access is denied
The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
Apache Tomcat/9.01
```

Also when I log into the web interface using the admin account I cannot access anything. The data is however still served. This leads me to believe it is some kind of protection from Geoserver and/or Tomcat against DDoS or brute force attacks. I do not have another account with admin rights.

How do I re-enable access to the Geoserver? I already tried restarting the task of the AWS EC2 instance, but no luck. Do I need to reconfigure Tomcat?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, no I idea how geserver is not authenticating users anymore, it is instead given them ANONYMOUSE role which leads to Forbidden error messages in the app log stacktraces.